# lateinit property colorPalettesDB has not been initialized - adding second Room database to application causes all Espresso tests to fail

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-espresso

I am creating a pixel art editor app for Android, and I have two databases, one that stores the users' creations, and another that stores the users' color palettes.

Here's the code for the color palettes database:

```
package com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.database

import android.content.Context
import androidx.room.Database
import androidx.room.Room
import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
import androidx.sqlite.db.SupportSQLiteDatabase
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.converters.JsonConverter
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.dao.ColorPalettesDao
import com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.models.ColorPalette
import kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import java.util.concurrent.Executors

@Database(entities = [ColorPalette::class], version = 3)
abstract class ColorPalettesDatabase: RoomDatabase() {
    abstract fun colorPalettesDao(): ColorPalettesDao

    companion object {
        private var instance: ColorPalettesDatabase? = null
        fun getDatabase(context: Context): ColorPalettesDatabase {
            if (instance == null) {
                synchronized(ColorPalettesDatabase::class) {
                    if (instance == null) instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext, ColorPalettesDatabase::class.java, AppData.colorPalettesDBFileName).fallbackToDestructiveMigration().addCallback(object : RoomDatabase.Callback() {
                        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
                            super.onCreate(db)
                            Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute {
                                CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                                    instance?.colorPalettesDao()?.insertColorPalette(ColorPalette("Default color palette", JsonConverter.convertListOfIntToJsonString(ColorDatabase.toList()), true))
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }).allowMainThreadQueries().build()
                }
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

When the Room database is first created, the 'Default' color palette is added.

Dao:

```
@Dao
interface ColorPalettesDao {
    @Insert
    suspend fun insertColorPalette(colorPalette: ColorPalette)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ColorPalette")
    fun getAllColorPalettes(): LiveData<List<ColorPalette>>

    @Query("DELETE FROM ColorPalette WHERE objId=:colorPaletteId")
    fun deleteColorPalette(colorPaletteId: Int)

    @Query("UPDATE ColorPalette SET item_color_palette_color_data=:colorData WHERE objId=:id_t")
    fun updateColorPaletteColorData(colorData: String, id_t: Int)
}
```

AppData:

```
class AppData {
    companion object {
        var pixelArtDBFileName = "pixel_art_db"
        lateinit var pixelArtDB: PixelArtDatabase

        var colorPalettesDBFileName = "color_palettes_db"
        lateinit var colorPalettesDB: ColorPalettesDatabase
    }
}
```

The data is loaded into the RecyclerView like so:

```
fun CanvasActivity.extendedSetUpRecyclerView() {
    val layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 1)
    layoutManager.orientation = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL
    binding.activityCanvasColorPickerRecyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager

    AppData.colorPalettesDB.colorPalettesDao().getAllColorPalettes().observe(this) {
        val toShow = if (fromDB != null) fromDB else it.first()
        binding.activityCanvasColorPickerRecyclerView.adapter = ColorPickerAdapter(toShow!!, this)
    }
}
```

Here are some of my Espresso tests:

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4ClassRunner::class)
class CanvasActivityTest {
    @get:Rule
    var activityTestRule = ActivityScenarioRule(CanvasActivity::class.java)

    @Test fun uitest_activityCanvasRootLayout_childViews_doNotExist() {
        for (id in EspressoUtilities.getActivityCanvasRootLayoutChildElementIds()) onView(withId(id)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test fun uitest_fullscreenMenuItem_isDisplayed() {
        onView(withId(R.id.fullscreen)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test fun uitest_undoMenuItem_isDisplayed() {
        onView(withId(R.id.undo)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test fun uitest_zoomIn_isDisplayed() {
        onView(withId(R.id.zoom_in)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test fun uitest_zoomOut_isDisplayed() {
        onView(withId(R.id.zoom_out)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }

    @Test fun uitest_saveProject_isDisplayed() {
        onView(withId(R.id.save_project)).check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

Running the Espresso test causes the following exception:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property colorPalettesDB has not been initialized
at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.database.AppData$Companion.getColorPalettesDB(AppData.kt:9)
at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.activities.canvas.CanvasActivity_setUpRecyclerViewKt.extendedSetUpRecyclerView(CanvasActivity+setUpRecyclerView.kt:15)
at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.activities.canvas.CanvasActivity.setUpRecyclerView(CanvasActivity.kt:45)
at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.activities.canvas.CanvasActivity_onCreateKt.extendedOnCreate(CanvasActivity+onCreate.kt:13)
at com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.activities.canvas.CanvasActivity.onCreate(CanvasActivity.kt:19)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
at androidx.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:769)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3612)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3796)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2214)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
```

This is strange because `colorPalettesDB` should've already been intialized at this stage. The other database which stores the users' creations is not causing any issues, but for some reason the `ColorPalettesDatabase` is the database causing these exceptions. Initializing it a second time in `onCreate` and in the Espresso code does not fix the problem, so I'm confused how I would fix this, as I'm unsure what the source of the error is.

---

Adding

```
  Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext(),ColorPalettesDatabase::class.java).build()
```

...does not fix the issue.

---

*Here is where the database gets initialized:*

```
fun MainActivity.initializeRoomDatabases() {
    AppData.pixelArtDB = PixelArtDatabase.getDatabase(this)
    AppData.colorPalettesDB = ColorPalettesDatabase.getDatabase(this)
}
```

```
public override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setBindings()
        setOnClickListeners()
        setTitle()
        initializeRoomDatabases()
    }
```

Comment: So where does your code initialize that variable? Why isn't your code calling `ColorPalettesDatabase.getInstance(context)` instead of using a `lateinit` variable at all?

Comment: @ianhanniballake because AppData is just an `Object` it has no way of accessing the application context... That's why it needs to be called from the Activity. If I am not doing something right let me know, most of the structuring of the code is based from a Udemy course.

Comment: Maybe you use colorPalettesDB in setBindings(),

because in your stack trace there is a place that said at this part of code try to use colorPalettersDB: CanvasActivity_setUpRecyclerViewKt.extendedSetUpRecyclerView

Comment: @MohammadRezaKhahani Sorry, I do not follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use the code below in your tests.

```
Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, TestDatabase::class.java).build()
```

more info: [Test and debug your database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/testing-db)

**Update:**

The error said that you have to initialize colorPalettesDB somehow. Maybe you should define it in the DI.

**Update 2:**

I think maybe the method CanvasActivity.extendedSetUpRecyclerView() called before MainActivity.initializeRoomDatabases() in your Activity, so the AppData.colorPalettesDB is not initialized.

Comment: I'm not testing my database though, this is an Espresso test. I have also never had to add this code when I had only one Room database in my code, can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: To add - adding this code in my `@Before` function does not fix this problem.

Comment: Your second point doesn't seem to make sense... How can a method in CanvasActivity be called before a method in MainActivity when you need to go through the MainActivity to navigate to the CanvasActivity.

If you mean about the unit tests then yes maybe that's why there is a problem, as it only launches the Espresso test in CanvasActivity directly without going through MainActivity. The strange thing is, even when I do initialize the database in CanvasActivity I still get the same error in Espresso.

Contact me on Discord: Tom Joney#5406 let's talk about it more

Comment: Yes if you go straight to ``CanvasActivity`` without creating a ``MainActivity`` first, that field won't be initialised. If you move that initialisation code into ``CanvasActivity``, it has to run before you call ``extendedSetupRecyclerView``. ``lateinit`` is just you promising the compiler that you'll set a value on that field *before* you try to read from it - if you're still getting that same crash, you haven't done that